# Textfield in WebView in an Android is hidden by the keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, webview

When I touch the html textfield, the soft keyboard pops up, and hides the textfield, so that I was not able to see what I had typed.

How to add vertical scroll for scrolling hidden content?

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare soft keyboard value appropriately in AndroidManifest.xml

Here is link for reference of values need to be set

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

check "`android:windowSoftInputMode`" in above link

Comment: Yes, "android:windowSoftInputMode" was exhibited in my AndroidManifest.xml:
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
It is still not working.

Comment: have u try "adjustPan" instead of "adjustResize"

Comment: Did anyone got the solution, I have stuck for the same